# Using contains key with file_get_contents

Tags: file-get-contents

So I'm trying to read a JSON file at a seperate url and based off what what is in the JSON file I would like for the program to do something. But the way I'm currently trying to do it is not working.

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://direct.cyberkitsune.net/canibuycubeworld/status.json');
//echo $homepage;
if($homepage contains 'f'){
echo 'true';
}else{
echo 'Something went terribly wrong!";
}
?>
```

This is the error that I get

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/a1285224/public_html/cubeworld.php on line 4
```

When I searched up the "file_get_contents" under the php manual it says that it should read the entire file into a string, so I'm a little confused why I'm getting a string error.

Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

In stead of 'contains', see the [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function. Also, you must close single quotes with single quotes, and double quotes with double quotes.

i.e.

```
$homepage = file_get_contents("http://direct.cyberkitsune.net/canibuycubeworld/status.json");

// echo $homepage;

if (strpos($homepage, "f") !== false)
    {
      echo "true";
    }
else
    {
      echo "Somethingwentterriblywrong!";
    }
```

Based on what you are trying to do, also see PHP's [JSON library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php).

To get the JSON data, you can use json_decode.

To dump all vars:

```
$json = json_decode($homepage, true);
var_dump($json);
```

To get all the other data:

```
printf("Time: %s<br>Site: %s<br>Reg: %s<br>Shop: %s", $json['time'], $json['site'], $json['reg'], $json['shop']);
```